# How can I use the .parent() method to create a button that's specific to only one <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I'm using the jQuery plugin FullCalendar and I want to make a 'weekends' button that toggles weekends in the calendar. I made the button but I have multiple calendar views on the same page and the button appears on all of them and I only want it to appear on the main calendar.
So, I thought I could use the .parent() method so that only the calendar header with the class "calendar" would have the button. If you think you have a better solution feel free to share, here's my code:

```
var $('.fc-header').parent() = parent

if parent == ".calendar"
  $('.fc-header-left').append('<span class="weekends fc-button fc-button-today fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right fc-state-active"><span class="fc-button-inner"><span id="weekends" class="fc-button-content">weekends</span><span class="fc-button-effect"><span></span></span></span></span>');
  $("#weekends").click(function () {
});
```

I'm sure there are numerous issues with this code, that would be great if you could describe all of them, thanks!

Comment: Try changing `if parent == ".calendar"` to [`if (parent.hasClass('calendar')) {`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass)

Comment: Also, you have a mistake in your var declaration...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, 1st thing, your `var` declaration is not valid, you have it backwards.  You can not assign a variable name like that.  2nd, your `if` statement is wrong.  3rd, Your `$("#weekends").click()` event will not work on elements that get created dynamically.  You need to use `.on()` with all 3 parameters, in order to attach to dynamically created elements.  4th, Just grab the element you want with the correct class and skip all of the others, since you are adding a `class="calendar"` to the element you want right?  No need to check for all of this nonsense and grab the parent(s).

**Better Solution**: Just select the actual element instead of selecting all elements of `$('.fc-header')` like this (2 lines of code, no `if` statement, and less confusion):

```
$(".calendar").children(".fc-header-left").append('<span class="weekends fc-button fc-button-today fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right fc-state-active"><span class="fc-button-inner"><span id="weekends" class="fc-button-content">weekends</span><span class="fc-button-effect"><span></span></span></span></span>');

$(".calendar").on("click", ".fc-button-content", function() {
        // Perform click code here...
});
```

This code assumes that there is an element child that has a class of `fc-header-left` that is an immediate child of the element with the `calendar` class.  Ofcourse, I don't know how you set up your DOM since you didn't post any HTML, just jQuery, so I am taking an educated guess on this.

Answer (score 0):

you could check if the parent has the class "calendar"

```
var $parent = $('.fc-header').parent();
if($parent.hasClass('calendar')){
   $('.fc-header-left').append('...Your Button');
   //By the way I thing this event should be in the "weekends" class, not the id
   $(".weekends").click(function () {
      //your event code here
   });
}
```